# jQuery one firing once for each elment with class

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery:

```
$(".myClass").one("click", function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $("#noneselected").hide();
    alert("hidden");
});
```

With this HTML:

```
<p class="myClass">Click</p>
<p class="myClass">Click</p>
<p class="myClass">Click</p>
```

---

The problem:

The function is firing `onclick` once for each `.myClass`. I only want the `.one` to fire once for all of them, on the first click on any of them. I can't simply use `.on` and `.off` because I already have another `.on("click"` function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the click event from all `.myclass` elements after the first click

```
$(".myClass").one("click", function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $("#noneselected").hide();
    alert("hidden");
    $(".myClass").off('click')
});
```

But it will be safer to use namespace based click handers since there could be others who might register other click handers

```
$(".myClass").on("click.onlyonce", function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $("#noneselected").hide();
    alert("hidden");
    $(".myClass").off('click.onlyonce')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QMhaq/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [namespaced events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) or just give your event handler a name by using a function declaration or a named function expression:

```
var $elements = $(".myClass").on("click", function handler() {
    // ...
    $elements.off('click', handler);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about storing a hidden variable and checking to see if the function has fired?

```
var handler = (function() {
    var fired = false;

    return function(){
        if (fired) return; // don't run the handler if fired is true

        fired = true;
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $("#noneselected").hide();
        alert("hidden");
    }
}());
```